# Eclipse ctrl+space not working for Play 1.2.5

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am able to create a new application and import it into the workspace successfully. But when I do some change in index.html such as adding a list, I am not getting the code auto-generation help from Eclipse IDE.

I was following the video present in the below link:

`http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/home`

The author have used some black colour IDE (don't know whats the name of that IDE) and is getting the code auto-generation help.

Please let me know if I need to add some plugin or some other way to get the code auto-genertion support from Eclipse IDE. I am a beginner, hence without code auto-generation, it will be really very difficult for me.

Also, let me know some other IDE that might help me while using this framework.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'IDE' in the video is sublime text I believe.

There is an eclipse plugin for Play 1.x but it is not very good.  It does not do code-completion for the templates - which I think is what you are asking.  https://github.com/erwan/playclipse - it has some support for play constructs in templates, but it lacks all the HTML ones - which I'd rather choose over #{list}.

You should see code completion in your Java source files though.  I suggest you keep as much logic in the Java source anyway and try to keep any template code simple.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new into this Play Framework. Can you please suggest some reference materials which might help me in getting though the basic stuff required for getting sarted with this framework? I dont know ajax, jQuery, etc. Again, in the above video, the author used some tags such as ${list..}, etc etc which I am not aware of. Hence I am eagerly looking for some reference materials or some blogs which let you know about the basics of this framework. I have worked in JEE application which all are servlet driven but thats not the case here, hence struggline :( Please suggest

Comment: the tutorial is pretty good and so are the docs: www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5 but make sure you are looking at the right version (if you want play 1.x).  the template language is groovy with their own tags (and you can create your own as well).   template docs are here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/templates and there is also a copy of the docs on your local machine if you are running play ( at /@documentation ) - the cheat sheets are handy too: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/cheatsheet/commandLine